# Bisectors of two vertical angles are continuations of each other

Tags: geometry

This is a question from Kiselev's Geometry.
[image]

The way I argue is that since the $\angle ABC = \angle DBE$, $EB$ and $GB$ are their bisectors respectively, therefore $\angle ABE = \angle EBC = \angle DBG = \angle GBE$.

This proves that EB and BG is continuation of each other, otherwise, if any of the angle above is not equal to one another, we cannot have $\angle EBG=180^{\circ}$

Is my proof correct? Is there any other ways to prove this proposition?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. We can show using bisector definition and transitivity that $\angle ABF = \angle FBC = \angle DBG = \angle GBE$ (I think point between $A$ and $C$ should be $F$) . Then $\angle DBC = \angle DBG + \angle GBE + \angle EBC=180^{\circ}$ but we also have that $\angle GBF = \angle GBE + \angle EBC + \angle CBF=\angle GBE + \angle EBC + \angle DBG=180^{\circ}$

Answer (score 0):

I think easier is to say $\angle EBC=\angle DBG$ because they are half the vertical angles, then $\angle EBG=\angle CBD+\angle CBE-\angle DBG$